# Run bash script in response to HTTP POST

Tags: php, bash

I have been using the following PHP script to trigger a bash script on a server:

```
<?php
$output = shell_exec('cat update.sh | ssh -l some_user -i key foo.bar.com');
echo "<pre>$output</pre>";
?>
```

Due to issues beyond my control, we've changed servers, and I cannot run PHP (don't ask). Is there another language I can use here that will accomplish this task? Something I can target with an HTTP POST, obviously. Thanks.

Comment: Yes, I can run shell scripts. The only issue is installing PHP.

Comment: You could run bash in a cgi-bin environment; you're not handling POST data in the above code though, do you really need that?

Comment: @gonzoc0ding Were you triggering the script just by accessing it in the web browser or via cron or manually?  You could just copy that command into a bash script and run the script like `./stuff.sh`

Comment: Bash can be used to respond to requests via CGI-BIN

Comment: @drew010 Its in response to a Github POST hook, so it is necessary.

Comment: @gonzoc0ding That makes sense.  In that case any of the cgi examples below should do the trick.

Answer (score 2):

You could go old-school cgi-bin and run the bash script directly:

```
#!/bin/bash
x=`cat update.sh | ssh -l some_user -i key foo.bar.com`
echo <<EOL
Content-type: text/html

<pre>$x</pre>
EOL
```

Answer (score 1):

You could run a bash script directly with cgi.

```
#!/bin/bash

OUTPUT=`cat update.sh | ssh -l some_user -i key foo.bar.com`

# You must add following two lines before
# outputting data to the web browser from shell
# script
echo "Content-type: text/html"
echo ""

echo "<html><head><title>Demo</title></head><body>"
echo "$OUTPUT <br>"
echo "</body></html>"
```

Some code from [here](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/run-shell-script-from-web-page/)

Answer (score 0):

It depends on server configuration. Task is very simple, so you can do it in every (I guess) technology your provider provides ;)

If you have access to perl:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

++$|;
print '<pre>';
system ('your command 2>&1');
print '</pre>';
```

Python and many others are similar.